# Fluent Validator for when another property is true

Tags: fluentvalidation

I am trying to use FluentValidation to validate the property 'Username' if another property 'Found' is true.

```
Object Contains:
   string Username
   bool Found

RuleFor(x => x.Username)
    .NotEmpty().DependentRules(() => {
                RuleFor(y => y.Found).Equals(true); //Not valid syntax
            })
    .WithMessage("Not Found");
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `When` clause.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Username).NotEmpty().When(x => x.Found);
```

[Working example](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60868572)

The dependent rules is a bit different; basically the rules specified in the dependent rules block will only be tested if the rule they're attached to passes.

As per the [doco](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#dependent-rules)

```
RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull().DependentRules(() => {
  RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
});
```

> Here the rule against Forename will only be run if the Surname rule passes.

Comment: Thanks! does NotNull() work if the answer is a false bool? I thought null was different?

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? `NotNull()` is just an extension to a property validator, same as `NotEmpty()`. `RuleFor(x => x.Username).NotNull().When(x => x.Found);` would work in the same way e.g., when Found is true, ensure that Username is not null; when Found is false, the Username `NotNull()` validation rule will not be tested - the when condition has not been met

Comment: Sorry, I can be terrible at explaining questions. I don't think I needed the NotEmpty other than for different error messages. I want username to pass validation only when found is true. So if 'bob' is tested as a valid username, then found will be true and the username will be valid. I might be going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: I think I follow; you want to validate Username somehow (probably by querying a repo of some description to ensure you've got a User with that Username), then if that passes you want to set the Found property to true. Sound about right? How were you planning on validating the Username as valid?

Comment: Thats correct. I have a listener that tries to validate the username as the user types. When found it sets Found to true then the form should be valid :).

Comment: If you have a 'listener' that is checking the Username as the user types it in, and the listener is setting Found to true when you get a hit on the Username, then fluentvalidation isn't really involved in validating the Username. If you are using this 'listener' in conjunction with fluentvalidation to ensure the form is valid (assuming web app now), wouldn't you just add a rule like `RuleFor(x => x.Found).Equal(true).WithMessage("User not found");`? Found will be set to true once your listener has verified the Username is valid, the fluentvalidation rule will pass and the form will be valid.

Comment: Your right, I can just put the Found validation message next to the username... For some reason I thought that wouldn't work - I'm pretty out of practice. Thanks! Whats the best way to validate if a bool is true or false?

Comment: Never mind NotEqual(bool) seems to work, maybe it just doesn't work with Checkboxes.